# Linking to page with all posts

Tags: posts, links, homepage

I'm new to the Wordpress world.  I've read the template hierarchy document and read online, but, I wanted to get feedback from here on what the best way to do this would be.

What I'm trying to do is create a page that simply lists all of the posts that my site has.  I am creating my own theme and as a result the home page (front-page.php) is highly tweaked.  I do list recent posts, but, only their titles.  On my home page I would like to add a link to "See all blog posts".  I'm comfortable with the PHP code; I know how to display posts.  I'm just not sure what the best way to get a page that lists them all aside from the homepage is.

I'm sure this is very easy to accomplish, I'm just still working through the Wordpress structure so your advice is appreciated!

Comment: You can follow [the link](http://upthemes.com/blog/2011/07/how-to-build-a-custom-page-template-for-blog-posts/) for a detail tutorial on this. After this, you just need to [create a page](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fN-3DF-k4KQ), and for the specific page, you will need to choose the `blog template` (by this tutorial: "Blog Posts" template) and then publish. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [create a page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) with Loop inside. Then create a page "All My Posts" and assign the template you've created to it in "Page Attributes" section of "Edit Page" admin page.

You can link to this page from the Front Page using `get_page` function. [Function Reference/get page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page).

Comment: Your post paired with the documentation at http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was answered years ago, but for those looking for a solution that find this page, there is a MUCH easier solution.

1. Go to Posts > Categories and click on Quickedit for the default blog category called *Uncategorized*.
2. Rename *Uncategorized* to *Blog* and change the slug to *blog*.
3. Then, when you create new categories, select Blog as the parent category. (You can easily Edit existing categories to make them children of the Blog category also.)
4. Last, in Appearances > Menu, click on Categories and click on Blog to add it to your menu.

Now all new posts will automatically be in the blog category by default, or one of it's child categories, and all will show in one page (paginating to older posts after a certain number of posts most likely).

As an extra bonus, your blog posts are all now accessible at **yoursite.com/category/blog**